# How to not use LIMIT when using DISTINCT with SQLiteDatabase query method?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I want to use the SQL `SELECT DISTINCT book FROM bible ORDER BY book;` using the SQliteDatabase **query** method, I try :-

```
Cursor csr = mDB.query(true,TABLE_BIBLE,new String[]{COL_BIBLE_BOOK},whereclause,whereargs,null,null,COL_BIBLE_BOOK,"-999");
```

Two of the 4 query have boolean true for DISTINCT, both have to have LIMIT parameter. SQLite says negative for no limit but doing this gives error like

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bible/com.example.bible.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid LIMIT clauses:-999
```

I know you can do with **rawQuery** but it not recommended to use it from Android Devloper Guide. So want to use **query**.

I know also you can do using large number that not good though it can confuse.

Comment: What is your intention with `LIMIT -999`?  Why are you not using a positive number?  By the way, using a native query is not so bad in this case, because there isn't much risk in being tightly coupled to SQLite running on the phone.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen negative number is no limit.

Comment: Then what is the point of even using a `LIMIT` clause in the first place?  This is probably the reason why the API is rejecting it; it doesn't see the point.  What is your intend SQL query?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen API wants LIMIT, in question first SQL not have LIMIT.  Says *public Cursor query (boolean distinct, 
                String table, 
                String[] columns, 
                String selection, 
                String[] selectionArgs, 
                String groupBy, 
                String having, 
                String orderBy, 
                **String limit**)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **null** *(like for most of the other parameters (except the 1st (table name))* :-

```
Cursor csr = mDB.query(true,TABLE_BIBLE,new String[]{COL_BIBLE_BOOK},whereclause,whereargs,null,null,COL_BIBLE_BOOK,null);
```

Alternately you can include DISTINCT (in this case) along with the column name e.g. :-

```
Cursor csr = mDB.query(TABLE_BIBLE,new String[]{"DISTINCT " + COL_BIBLE_BOOK},whereclause,whereargs,null,null,COL_BIBLE_BOOK);
```

The first would likely be the preferable.

Answer (score 1):

> SQLite says negative for no limit

Where does it say so? I read the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) as:

> Passing null denotes no LIMIT clause.

...

> I know you can do with rawQuery but it not recommended to use it from Android Devloper Guide

`rawQuery()` is just fine, even if the API designers wanted you to use fancier methods for constructing the SQL.

---

> SELECT say If the LIMIT expression evaluates to a negative value, then there is no upper bound on the number of rows returned

That's true and works in raw sqlite SQL.

If you use `query()`, you get additional validation from `SQLiteQueryBuilder` that throws this exception you're seeing. See the [source](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.java#208).

Comment: [SELECT](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html) say *If the LIMIT expression evaluates to a negative value, then there is no upper bound on the number of rows returned.*

Comment: Right, but again, what is the point of doing this?  If you don't want an upper limit, then just leave out `LIMIT` :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Some round the round. SQL in question working good. Change to Android query has 4 buildres. 2 builders with distinct. Both want limit as well as distinct not think of using null but triedout numbers and expressions.

Comment: @dintheb You're right about sqlite but it's the android sqlite wrapper causing your problem. Edited to add details.